# Is there an Android viewer that understands international language comments in PGN?

Tags: pgn, android

I have a PGN file, in which I can view non-English (Cyrillic) comments on my PC in Chessbase or in Notepad++, but all Android apps (playchess, masterchess, scid on the go, droidfish) I tried instead show garbage for the comments. Is there an app that is worth trying that might support this? Example below:

```
[Event "chessclub.com"]
[Site "-"]
[Date "2016.8.5"]
[Round "?"]
[White "PlayerA"]
[Black "PlayerB"]
[Result "0-1"]
[PlyCount "6"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 f5 {Белые сдались.} 0-1
```

Comment: Could you please post such a pgn here and i can try loading in my Analyze This app?

Comment: So you're asking for a PGN viewer with unicode support, aren't you? Or would you need further functionality as UCI engine integration for analysis and so on?

Comment: Added example with the comment that says "White resigned", and yes, a PGN viewer with unicode support would be sufficient for the purpose of this question; granted, support in desktop tools is also quite bad; e.g. exporting to PGN from Fritz works; exporting same data with Chessbase fails, pasting into neither works, and so on (I could elaborate ...);

Comment: @AAP did you have any luck getting it to work?

Comment: @Joe, sorry not sure how I missed this comment. I just pasted in Analyze This app and the comment was fine. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: ChessOK Playing Zone app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.convekta.android.chessplanet also imports your PGN fine.

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev but ... ChessOk only lets you paste a string, not import a file. or am I missing something? Ultimately I want to use a real-life pgn file for reviewing games.

Comment: @AAP what do you mean by 'pasted'? I have this string saved in a file, and when I imported it as a file in Analyze this, it showed garbage characters. I feel the settings/encoding for creating a pgn file is what matters, so I wonder what exactly you did.

Comment: ChessOK provide opening files from various file managers, but you can't import file from the main GUI.

Comment: @Artem Mostyaev Thanks, that allowed me to open the pgn file, but comments still show as garbage characters (and as a side note it feels like the ChessOk viewer only shows first game in the file with no way to see list of games).

Comment: @Joe: there are two ways to import the game in Analyze This: 1. Paste the pgn string via Menu - Paste or 2. Assuming your pgn file is already on your sdcard, you open it via the App's game browser (1st icon) - locate the file and then it will show all games in that file.

Comment: @AAP I loaded it up from the pgn file on the sdcard. I suspect the issue has to do with how one saves the text in my post into a text file (what encoding/software did you use? If that works for you and fails for me - that seems like the only thing that could explain the difference. The files I use show up well in Chessbase, but not in android apps).

Comment: The easiest way for you to correctly open the comments is re-encode file into UTF8. As Android was created in a UTF world, there is no need in encoding support. I suppose you file is in Win1251 encoding (ANSI). just recode in into UTF8 using some text editor as Notepad++.

Comment: @Artem Convert to UTF-8 in Notepad++ did the trick, thank you very much! It now works in playchess, Master chess, and probably most other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGN files need to be converted to UTF-8 as pointed out by @Artem Mostyaev, then most apps would support this.